# Can 200 status code be response for POST request

Tags: rest, api

I had assumed that POST should return 201 in case of success. But I have to call API with request body (something like GET + body), which is not supported and I'm going ahead with POST.

Since i fetch result(i. e list) when i hit API. Is it ok to return 200 as response , as 201 will be invalid since i'm not creating any new entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can 200 status code be response for POST request

Yes.  The relevant specification is currently RFC 7231, section 4.3.3

> almost all of the status codes defined by this specification might be received in a response to POST (the exceptions being 206 (Partial Content), 304 (Not Modified), and 416 (Range Not Satisfiable)).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

For `200 OK`, `POST` means `POST an entity describing or containing the result of the action;`